# Why doesn't sublime recognize the module I downloaded?

Tags: python, sublimetext

http://pmorissette.github.io/bt/index.html#what-is-bt

this is the module I want to use. After creating a python file in sublime,

```
import bt
```

gives me the error

```
ImportError: No module named bt
```

Even though the terminal declared the download to be successful. Also, I am able to run the line import bt on terminal without any errors. So it has to be an error on sublime. Sublime is running Python 3.3 which is fine. Do i have to link the module to sublime by putting the file relatively close to it? If so, I can't find it on Finder (I am using a mac).

Comment: Did you install to the correct version of Python? 2.7 should come as default for mac which is where it might have gone.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/ i assume sublime is using 3.3, right?

Comment: Open IDLE for 2.7 and 3.3, `import bt` in both and see which one works.

Comment: i can't find 2.7 IDLE anywhere on finder. But there are no errors when i run it on 3.6. This doesn't make any sense. Python is 3.6. Sublime seems to be 3.3. And my mac is 2.7 @StevenSummers

Comment: Uh, guess you don't have 2.7 then? Well you have confirmed that it was installed in 3.6 instead of 3.3. Did you want it in 3.3? You'll need to point to that when installing or have sublime use 3.6.

Comment: i'd rather use sublime in 3.6.

Comment: Just in case there is any confusion, the version of python embedded in Sublime Text 3 (3.3) has nothing to do with any versions of python that may or may not be installed on your machine. It's completely distinct and used only internally by Sublime for plugins. Sublime runs the external command `python` to run a python program, which means if you have no python interpreter installed, you can't run python programs from sublime. Additionally, `python` may be running a different version of python than you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your normal installation of python is **different** from the Sublime Text's python.

To use modules like this in your Sublime Text plugins, you should make a dependency (especially if you want to distribute your package).

---

You can find the code of your library by just printing it from python. Here's an example for pygame:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame
 <module 'pygame' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\pygame\\__init__.py'>
>>>
```

In this case, the code of pygame is located in `C:/Python34/lib/site-packages/pygame`.